# Please if someone help me to find the winning Probability

Tags: probability

you are playing a chess match against a skilled opponent .for a given game ,there is a 75% chance the game will end in a draw.of the game that do not end in a draw,there is a 2/3 chance you will win,and a 1/3 chance you will lose.the first player to win 2 games in a row is declared the winner of the chess match.what is the probability you will win the match?

Comment: What are your thoughts ? Pl. show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: The usual approach to a thing like this is to note that, any point, all you really care about is the result of the last game.  Thus you have $3$ active states according to whether $A$ won the last game, $B$ won the last game, neither won the last game (that includes START and cases where the prior game was a tie).  Set up equations for those three states and solve.

Comment: @lulu: I have tried a different approach, and am getting a slightly different answer, I wonder why. (Btw, the "draws" in tennis points can be attributed to numerous "lets" being called due to a noisy crowd in pre-COVID times !)

Comment: @trueblueanil  looking at what you wrote, you appear not to consider the possibility of a tie.  That would be fine if the question specified that the winner was the person who won two games in a row *of those games which have a winner*.  But that's not how I read the question.  That is to say, you consider $ADDBDADA$ to be a win for $A$ (where $D$ means "draw"), while I would say the series was still undecided (though $A$ might win the series on the next game).

Comment: @lulu: No, I am stipulating that one or other player must win two consecutive points, which is what is required at deuce in tennis. Deuce here means starting from scratch.

Comment: But in this game, having $B$ win a round does not take you back to scratch.  In this game $B$ winning instantly gives $B$ the advantage.  That is to say, $ABB$ is a winner for $B$ in this game, while in tennis (at deuce)  it just means advantage $B$.

Comment: @lulu: Hmm, I see... Idk whether it can easily be fixed. Thanks

Comment: @trueblueanil  well... The thing is, in this game, you *never* have to return to scratch.  In theory you could alternate $ABA\cdots $ or $BABA\cdots$ forever.  Worse, you could return to scratch, but only after a dozen rounds (or whatever).  That makes it hard to set up a calculation akin to yours.  Markov handles this by pointing out that you certainly have to either end the series or return to a prior state after a small number of games, though we don't know which prior state you return to.   That ends up being enough.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly let us find out your winning probability.

$\frac{1}{4}$ of games end in a draw in which you win $\frac{2}{3}$ of them hence your winning probability is $\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{6}$

Similarly the opponents probability of winning is $\frac{1}{12}$

We can break down  your probability of winning overall, i.e having 2 consecutive wins before your opponent on the three states the game can be in depending on the last result.

Let $\{ D,L,W\}$ be the states that indicate respectively the last game was a draw, a loss or a win.

Firstly our transition probabilities are as follows:

$D\to D \frac{3}{4}, D\to W\frac{1}{6}, D\to L \frac{1}{12}$ 
$L\to D\frac{3}{4}, L\to W \frac{1}{6}$ 
$W \to D \frac{3}{4}, W \to L \frac{1}{12}$

Hence:
$\mathbb{P}_D[\text{You win the match}] := \mathbb{P}[\text{You win the match} | \text{Most recent game was draw}] = \frac{3}{4}\mathbb{P}_D[\text{You win the match}] +\frac{1}{6}\mathbb{P}_W[\text{You win the match}] + \frac{1}{12}\mathbb{P}_L[\text{You win the match}]$

For shorthand let the event of you winning the match be $S$.

We have:

$\mathbb{P}_D[S] = \frac{3}{4}\mathbb{P}_D[S] +\frac{1}{6}\mathbb{P}_W[S] + \frac{1}{12}\mathbb{P}_L[S]$ 
$\mathbb{P}_W[S] = \frac{3}{4}\mathbb{P}_D[S] +\frac{1}{6}\cdot 1 + \frac{1}{12}\mathbb{P}_L[S]$ 
$\mathbb{P}_L[S] = \frac{3}{4}\mathbb{P}_D[S] +\frac{1}{6}\mathbb{P}_W[S] + \frac{1}{12}\cdot 0 $

Solving these equations yields: $\mathbb{P}_D[S] = \frac{26}{33} $

Notice that the most recent game being a draw is identical to the state when the game starts so your probability of winning is $\frac{26}{33}$

Comment: Rechecked your answer to  find it is just fine (+1)

Comment: @trueblueanil yes I know its fine, there were lots of people commenting on it, I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that the probabilities that you win, lose, and draw one game are

$\frac16,\; \frac1{12},\;$  and $\;\frac34$ respectively

Let there be $3\,$ *states,* **s** (**s**tart=level), **a** (**a**head by one ) and **b** (**b**ehind by one)

We seek the probability that you ultimately win starting from **s**

Note that from any stage you can draw and return to **s** with $Pr = 3/4$.

Tracking your movement from state to state from **s** to victory,

$s = 3s/4 + a/6 + b/12\quad$   **[I]**

Similarly, $a = 3s/4 + 1/6 +b/12\quad$ **[II]**

(Note that the second term , a win from **a** completes a win for you)

$b =  3s/4 + a/6\quad$ **[III]**

solving these $3$ linear equations gives us $P(\,you\; win) = s = \frac{26}{33}$